# Retrieving Char digits from a text file and appending them into a String?

Tags: c++, string, char, var

I am trying to get some chars read from a file and into a string. For example `@2%4$$3`. My program will take out `243` from the text file, now I need it to be in a string so I can convert it to two hundred and 43 and given to an `INT var`.

Any help would be Superbly appreciated! :) 
Thanks, 
Brian

Comment: Try to concat with + and convert like string _s+=_ch; then convert to numeric

Comment: Could you please tag your question with the language you are working in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char file_buff[1024]="!@25#3$#4";
    char num_buff[1024];
    int len,i,k;
    // open file and read the entire contents specied as per the size
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fgets(file_buff, 1024, f);
    printf("String read: %s\n", file_buff);
    fclose(f);
    len=strlen(file_buff);
    // parse the buffer for digits and store it in a buffer
    for(i=0,k=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if((file_buff[i] >= 0x30) && (file_buff[i] <= 0x39))
        {
            num_buff[k]=file_buff[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    num_buff[k]='\0';
    printf("%s",num_buff);
    return 0;
}
```